# Get strings from two files bash

Tags: linux, bash, file, for-loop

I have two files, one with url's other with id's

```
for line in $(cat urls_file); do
for id in $(cat ids_file); do
touch topic_$id
curl $line|grep "data\-topic=">topic_$id
done
done
```

BUT it does for every $line all the $id 's and i want to do for each line each id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> BUT it does for every $line all the $id 's and i want to do for each line each id.

In that case you should use `paste` to have 2 column data from 2 input files:

```
while read -r line id; do
   curl "$line" | grep 'data-topic=' > "topic_$id"
done < <(paste urls_file ids_file)
```

There is no need to use `touch` as `curl` will create the file anyway.